# VS code can't import module which is already installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, visual-studio-code, terminal

[image: Inslalled module]

[image: VS code error message]

I've already installed the module "pandas" through pip3, and it's visible through `pip3 list`.
But VS code still showing the error message. I was trying to set up some breakpoints to test my code in VS code. It works fine while in the terminal.

Comment: try changing the interpreter path or just restart vscode

Comment: could it be possible that you have multiple python installations and VS Code is set to work with different one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you selected the correct Python Interpreter inside of VSCode?

If you have the Python extension installed, you can go into your command palette (Ctrl+Shift+P or Cmd+Shift+P or F1), type in `Python: Select Interpreter`, select the correct environment and VSCode should be able to recognize it.

In case that's the issue :)

Comment: where do I find command prompt? Excuse me I'm pretty new

Comment: Open the Command Palette (⇧⌘P), depending on the operating system. Should be ctrl+shift+p.

Docs: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface