# VSCode does not recognize installed packages, despite correct interpreter selected and correct environment

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to do some forecasting using facebook prophet using an environment named `'fbprophet'` where I've installed several dependencies. However when I select the correct interpreter and run `'import pandas as pd'` I get the error: `'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas''`. I've tried restarting VSCode as well as the suggested solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64172961/vs-code-cant-import-module-which-is-already-installed?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56658553/why-do-i-get-a-modulenotfounderror-in-vs-code-despite-the-fact-that-i-already) but none of them have been of any help. Below is some screen shots of my VSCode settings.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to restart your computer? Several months ago I had the same problem, tried the same solutions than you, and nothing worked. I shutdown the computer and the next day everything worked fine.

Comment: Hi @Laideen - No I have not tried this and will do so later. I hope the solution is THAT simple. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to choose the interpreter with `pandas` installed, and then use `Run Python File` to execute the program.

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

For jupyter, you need to choose the right kernel:

[image]

Comment: Hello, I have already chosen the interpreter with pandas installed, as my screenshots suggest. However, I don't have the option like you, to choose "Run Pythoon File". It's nowhere to be found.

Comment: How do you execute the script? Use code to check your interpreter.

Comment: I'm using Jupyter notebook in VSCode. So either "ctrl/shift + enter" or pressing the arrow next to the code cell. What do you mean by "use code to check the interpreter"?

Comment: You are using jupyter. Why not make it clear in the question? Why not show your jupyter interface? Is the kernel version in the upper right corner correct?

Comment: Because when I posted this I thought it should not make a difference whether I use .ipynb or just a simple .py file as the underlying issue is should affect both in the same way, but I see your point. I'll edit the question to include that. If, by "kernel version" you mean "python version", then yes it's correct. I'm on 3.11.4.

Comment: There is of course a difference, because selecting the interpreter only works for py files, for ipynb you need to select the kernel for it. This is different.

Comment: Ah, I see now. I never understood the kernel vs interpreter difference. I solved it now, thank you very much for clarifying!

Comment: Glad this worked for you and wish you a happy life.